# Оптимизировать код без использования словаря

Tags: python, django, pagination

Ревьюер написал замечание: "Тут нужно просто возвращать страницу, без обертки в словарь."

Но если убрать словарь у меня не проходят тесты

```
def get_page_context(queryset, request): 
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, settings.COUNT_POSTS_PAGE) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page') 
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number) 
    return { 
        'page_obj': page_obj, 
    }
```

Comment: Ну значит перепишите весь остальной код так, чтобы он смог работать без этого словаря и стал успешно проходить тесты, в чём проблема?

Comment: Вероятно, ревьюер имел ввиду, что нужно возвращать объект `page_obj` напрямую, а в месте использования функции (ее переименовать тогда нужно в `get_page_obj`) уже вставлять этот `page_obj` в контекст (я так понимаю, что вы сейчас там сливаете два словаря).

Comment: Спасибо, учту1!